# Online citation style

Tags: citations

Is there a predominant accepted style for citing online? The reason I ask is because some styles use underlining, but underlining online should only be used for links.

To be clear - the *source* I'm citing can be a book or a magazine or an article. The *place* I'm putting the citation for people to see is on a website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being that this is for a website, I am not sure as to what kind of information you are looking to post.  In this [site](http://www.lib.vt.edu/find/citation/) you will find a list of all the styles of citation that can be used.  [Academically](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/08/), MLA and APA are the 2 main ones used, but if this is for technical purposes such as medical or electronic research, they have their own citations.  It is hard to tell you which style without knowing the content and context to which the information is being presented, however, the first link should provide you a list with all formats so you can pick which one you would feel is best.  If you feel that MLA or APA are the styles you want to use, there are plenty of websites that will generate the citation for you.  You just need to enter in the adequate information.  A popular site widely used would be [CitationMachine](http://www.citationmachine.net/apa/cite-a-website).

To answer the main question though, the style isn't related to the *place* you  are writing, but rather the *type* and *style* of writing you are trying to do.

commonly online, I have found the quotes to be numbered off with subscript or superscript and then at the bottom associate that number to the reference link.  Not sure if that falls under one of those styles but that is just a personal observation of online references used.  However, to also point out, there is a [difference](https://plagiarism.arts.cornell.edu/tutorial/logistics3.cfm) between references, and citations.

Comment: I suppose I was trying to over simplify the problem.  I have multiple things to reference from multiple disciplines.  I know there are multiple styles - I was hoping there was one style that is commonly accepted as the style to use when posting online.  It seems life is not that simple though.  Thanks for the references.

Comment: Man don't we all wish.  Luckily, at least for academics, we were able to use MLA or APA for all of our papers regardless of topic or if otherwise requested.  So the only thing I would have to suggest would be to use the style that would relate to the main theme/subject of the entry.  Not sure though if using multiple style citations would be considered taboo or not within 1 body of work.